# Convert Address Data type to Text in a formula field

Tags: salesforce

I'm integrating Zoom Info into Salesforce. I have three fields.

- Zoom Info Custom Field =  ZI_Company_Address__c formula return type text)
  **(holds the following formula)**
  Zoom_Info_Contact_Street__c +BR()+
  Zoom_Info_Contact_City__c + ", " + Zoom_Info_Contact_State__c + " " + Zoom_Info_Contact_Zip_Code__c +BR()+
  Zoom_Info_Contact_Country__c
  *this result gives me*: an output of
- 123 elm Street
  City, State 07920
  United States
- My Salesforce Field  - MailingAddress (SF Field of Address Type)
  *this result is what the Salesforce User entered on the record*: an output of
- 10 elm Street
  City, State 01111
  United States

I'm simply trying to compare the two.
IF(AND(MailingAddress = ZI_Company_Address__c),"Yes","No")

Getting this error:  Error: Incorrect argument type for operator '='.